# which one is better from performance point of view..arraylist or array?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I want to store 50000 or more strings and I need to perform several operations like retrieval of a specific string, deletion of a specific string, etc. I have been given only two options to select from and these are array list and array to store them. From a performance point of view which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither.  If you want retrieval of specific strings (e.g. get the string "Foo") and deleting specific strings (e.g. delete "Foo"), I would consider using a `Set`.

An array list or an array will give you O(N) retrieval (unless you keep it sorted).  A `Set` will typically give you at least O(lg N) time for finding a specific item.

Comment: Why a `Set` and not a `Map`?He may want duplicates

Comment: The question didn't give any information about values associated with the strings, so a `Set` seemed more natural.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is backed by an array so performance wise you should see no difference.

If there is no error in your requirements, and indeed you have to choose among only an arraylist and a raw array, I would suggest an arraylist since you have all the APIs to manipulate the data available which you would have to write yourself for a raw array of `String`s.

Comment: An abstraction always incurs at least *some* overhead. Python is "backed" by C which is "backed" by x86 (in my computer at least), but that doesn't mean I'll get the same performance with Python as I would if I used assembly code.

Comment: @NullUserException:I used to strongly believe that but I keep reading in various links that `Java` (interpretted and backed by C) is not slower than `C++` and is occusionally it is faster

Comment: Typically, the `indexOf` operation of ArrayList (which is one of the operations the OP mentions) does exactly what you would do with an array - not a single extra line.

Comment: @assylias, wrt `indexOf` even if it does exactly what you would do with an array, it is still an extra method invocation.  Admittedly it is negligible and there is a good chance that it will be compiled away (I don't really know about that), but array should always be as fast or (negligibly) faster than ArrayList.

Comment: @emory What extra method invocation? Edit: ok understood, the fact of calling indexOf... That is a few nanoseconds I suppose. But I would hope that even using arrays, the code is not going to be one big 1000 LOC method!

Comment: @assylias Exactly.  In most situations, the convenience of using ArrayList outweighs the negligible performance penalty.  If I wrote code to perform the `indexOf` operation, I would have to spend time debugging it.  If instead I used the ArrayList `indexOf` method, I would just assume it had already been debugged.  However, if performance was ultra critical, the extra hassle might be worth it.

Comment: @emory:If you compare the access of an array element using the index you are correct.The method invocation incurs some overhead.But I don't think your comparison is correct here, since there would be code arround the array to access it, effectively implementing a `List` using it.So you will have more than `array[i]` anyway

Answer (score 1):

an array is more efficient performance wise than an arraylist but unless you know how many elements you will be placing into an array an arraylist would be a better option since the size of the arraylist can grow as needed whereas a static array cannot.

Comment: Strange answer.1)Why would you assume a static array?2)An arraylist is backed by an array.

Comment: a static array can "grow" just like an ArrayList the only difference is you have to write the growing function (creating a new array, and copying the data) yourself which ArrayList does for you automatically.

Comment: An array[] is static in size at creation and yes an arraylist uses an array internally but they are not the same since when you create a new array, and copying the data in the original array yourself you have just reinvented the arraylist and are back to O(n). The question was regarding which was faster performance wise and an array is faster performance wise over an arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

An array will always have better performance than an `ArrayList`. In part, because when using an array you don't have to pay the extra cost of type-casting its elements (using generics doesn't mean that typecasts disappear, only that they're hidden from plain view).

To make my point: [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) and [fastutil](http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/) are a couple of very fast Java collections libraries, which rely on the fact of providing type-specific collections and not Object-based implementations like `ArrayList` does.

Also, there's a cost for using a `get()` method for accessing elements (albeit small) and a cost for resizing operations, which can be important in huge `ArrayLists` with many insertions and deletions. Of course, this doesn't happen with arrays because by their very nature have a fixed size, that's both an advantage and a disadvantage.

Answering your question: if you know in advance the number of elements that you're going to need, and those elements aren't going to change much (insertions, deletion) then your best bet is to use an array. If some modification operations are needed and performance is of paramount importance, try using either Trove or fastutil.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense to me.But if it is not measured I am not sure that there is such performance difference between these.Do you have some link that specifies some measurements?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieval of specific string,deleting specific string...i think ArrayList is not the best solution. Take a look at HashSet or LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code of ArrayList](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html) you will see:

```
  107       /**
  108        * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
  109        * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer.
  110        */
  111       private transient Object[] elementData;
```

it is using an array internally.

So ArrayList could never be faster than using an array.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you intially size the ArrayList correctly, the main difference will come from additions, which do a range check that you could get rid of with an array. But we are talking about a few CPU cycles here.

Apart from that there should be no noticeable difference. For example, the `indexOf` method in ArrayList looks like this:

```
   public int indexOf(Object o) {
       if (o == null) {
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
               if (elementData[i]==null)
                   return i;
       } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
               if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                   return i;
       }
       return -1;
   }
```